# setBandLevel under Lollipop

Tags: android, equalizer

Hey I made an equalizer app and now users are complaining about not being able to adjust bands when using Android 5.0. I don't think it's necessary to write down the whole MainActivity, touches are being received just like they would on other phones but the line

```
eq.setBandLevel ((short)i, (short)level);
```

Seems to have no effect on >= Android 5.0 whatsoever.

Any thoughts on this?

Edit: so if people are curious:

```
 eq = new Equalizer (0, 0); // <-----
        if (eq != null)
          {
          eq.setEnabled (true); // <-----
          int num_bands = eq.getNumberOfBands();
          num_sliders = num_bands;
          short r[] = eq.getBandLevelRange();
          min_level = r[0];
          max_level = r[1];
          for (int i = 0; i < num_sliders && i < MAX_SLIDERS; i++)
            {
            int[] freq_range = eq.getBandFreqRange((short)i);
            sliders[i].setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
            slider_labels[i].setText (formatBandLabel (freq_range));
            }
          }
        for (int i = num_sliders ; i < MAX_SLIDERS; i++)
          {
          sliders[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
          slider_labels[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
          }
```

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense without us seeing an implementation of the equalizer. Can you attach the relevant source code?

Comment: Updated, just in case that matters